# Preferred method to get comment reply link for comments with a depth of 0

Tags: comments

By default, `get_comment_reply_link` doesn't work for comments with a depth of 0, since the function contains the statement:

```
if ( 0 == $args['depth'] || $args['max_depth'] <= $args['depth'] )
        return;
```

You can override this problem by specifying a depth greater than 0 in the `$args` of the `get_comment_reply_link` call.  But if this function ignores comments with a depth of 0 by default, is there a different preferred method to get a reply link for top-level comments?

Context:

- [comment_reply_link doesn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547040/comment-reply-link-doesnt-show) on Stack Overflow--see top reply
- [Official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_reply_link/) for the `get_comment_reply_link` function

### Edit

I was asked how I was getting a depth of 0.

comments.php:

```
if(have_comments()) {
    wp_list_comments(array(
        'status'  => 'approve',
        'walker' => new comment_walker()
    ));
```

functions.php:

```
class comment_walker extends Walker_Comment {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        $output .= var_dump($depth);
    }
}
```

This outputs `int(0)` for as many comments as I have, even if I change the parameters for `start_el` to `$depth = 1`.

### Edit #2

This is is the code that's actually using `get_comment_reply_link` in functions.php.  It works only if I modify the depth with the line marked below, otherwise it uses the depth of 0 and returns a null value:

```
class comment_walker extends Walker_Comment {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        $comment_id = intval($item->comment_ID);
        $post_id = intval($item->comment_post_ID);
        $max_depth = get_option('thread_comments_depth');
        $default = array(
            'depth'      => 1, // doesn't work unless I add this line to change the depth
            'max_depth'  => $max_depth
        );
        $output .= get_comment_reply_link($default,$comment_id,$post_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you getting a comment with depth 0? Comment depth starts at 1 so a comment with no parent has a depth of 1. Depths of 0 indicate a bug in your code

Comment: please avoid putting blocks of code in comments, comments only support inline code. It's very likely though that you've made a mistake by setting depth to 0. Also your link to the official docs is incorrect, instead of linking to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_reply_link/ you've linked to its code in an ancient version of WordPress

Comment: Okay.  I'm not sure how to answer you without having to put in a block of code.

In answer to your question, I'm calling a walker function.  In the walker, I'm using `start_el`.  Even if I set `depth=1`, if I output the depth of each comment, I get a `int(0)` for all top-level comments.

In your linked current documentation, the function I referred to is at Line 1691-1693.

Comment: you can edit your question using the edit link under the tags, can you also add the code that tries to use `get_comment_reply_link`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a depth 0 comment, and it should never happen, here is your problem:

```php
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        $output .= var_dump($depth);
```

No depth incrementing is happening so it is always 0. `start_el` has several responsibilities as part of the walking, and for comment loop setup.

If we look at the `start_el` method of the `Walker_Comment` class, the first thing it does is increment the depth and set the necessary global variables:

```php
    public function start_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        // Restores the more descriptive, specific name for use within this method.
        $comment = $data_object;

        $depth++;
        $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth;
        $GLOBALS['comment']       = $comment;
```

Since yours doesn't do this, `$depth` will never be incremented no matter how deep the walker goes, and will always remain at the default `0`. You should also expect lots of PHP warnings as a result of the globals being undefined.

However, if implemented correctly, `$depth` will always be `1` or higher, and `get_comment_reply_link` will never receive a `0` value.

This and other functions need to do several other things as well to behave correctly as a comment walker. As a rule of thumb, copy paste the entirety of the method you're replacing in your custom walker, then modify it, but don't delete it entirely and start from scratch.

Comment: I might not be understanding fully, but since I'm using `extends`, am I not adding onto the existing functions of the defined functions, rather than overwriting them?  I thought that because it seems like `start_el` is incrementing somehow even with the code as-is. If I add a child comment `$output .= var_dump($depth);`, the child comment gives me `int(1)`, while all parent comments give me `int(0)`.

Comment: no, unless you explicitly call the parent method, yours replaces it fully. `extend` is just the keyword PHP uses for classic inheritance. This is why Widgets have a `parent::__construct(` call in their constructor. Even then, using `parent::start_el` wouldn't work well here